# My java functions throws a nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am trying to call a function in another one but I get a nullpointerException as well as many other errors..

```
public float maxFat() {

    SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
            "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    float cals = customSharedPreference.getFloat("calpref", 0f);
    float maxfat = cals / 36;

    return maxfat;
}
```

And here is where i call it

```
public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getFatDataset() {

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from dailystats;", null);
    float i = 1.0f;

    c.moveToFirst();
    XYSeries seriesFat = new XYSeries("Fat");
    XYSeries seriesMaxFat= new XYSeries("Maximum Fat");
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        seriesFat.add(i++, c.getDouble(2));
        StatsActivity stats= new StatsActivity();
        seriesMaxFat.add(i, stats.maxFat());
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    dataset.addSeries(seriesFat);
    dataset.addSeries(seriesMaxFat);
    return dataset;
}
```

Here is the log file

```
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at com.nutriapp.StatsActivity.maxFat(StatsActivity.java:183)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at com.nutriapp.DatabaseAdapter.getFatDataset(DatabaseAdapter.java:396)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at com.nutriapp.FatActivity.getIntent(FatActivity.java:52)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at com.nutriapp.StatsActivity$1.onClick(StatsActivity.java:127)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-05 11:39:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(31282):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 11:39:22.937: D/dalvikvm(31282): GC_CONCURRENT freed 135K, 3% free 9633K/9863K, paused 17ms+29ms
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.nutriapp/databases/nutriwellness.db' 
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at com.nutriapp.DatabaseAdapter.open(DatabaseAdapter.java:215)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at com.nutriapp.FatActivity.getIntent(FatActivity.java:49)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at com.nutriapp.StatsActivity$1.onClick(StatsActivity.java:127)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/SQLiteDatabase(31282):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 11:39:23.047: E/System(31282): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2090)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2182)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2178)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2143)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:1914)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
05-05 11:39:23.098: E/System(31282):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Is your `getSharedPreferences()` returning a null?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: In its class, it is not. It's working fine !

Comment: Where _exactly_ do you get the NPE? Did you debug an check what is null and why that could be the case?

Comment: When you see the NullPointerException information, Java also tells you the "Stack trace" with the information about which classes and methods are called at what line numbers, copy that here. It will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: `com.nutriapp.StatsActivity.maxFat(StatsActivity.java:183)` show us 183th line of `StatsActivity`

Comment: Here it is Boris   SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: But in the class StatsActivity, it is not null. It is stored in the disk and i can retrieve the values correctly.

Comment: The best thing to do is to run this code in a debugger and see exactly what is null.  You seem to be having problems believing what the compiler is telling you, since you insist that everything is "fine".  You'll continue to get this error until you stop insisting that your code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the class `StatsActivity` extend `Activity`?  If so, you cannot use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of the class, and you need to rethink your application design.

Comment: How can I get an instance of it please?

Comment: You can't "get" an instance of it. You start a new `Activity` by creating an `Intent` and calling `startActivity`.  Read about the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and the [application fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing cursor that's why you are getting database not closed exception.
just do

`c.close()`

In your XYMultipleSeriesDataset function after you have done with cursor.